# Foundation symbol not found in Xcode 9 beta 4?

Tags: ios, swift, carthage

I just switched from Xcode 9 beta 3 to beta 4 the other day, and now I get the following error when I use the `OAuthSwift` library to connect to Discogs.com. It doesn't seem to be a problem on either `OAuthSwift` or Discogs' part, though, because the error is:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __T0SS10FoundationE9substringS2S13CharacterViewV5IndexV2to_tF
  Referenced from: /Users/nrith/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<blah-blah-blah>.app/Immediate.app/Frameworks/OAuthSwift.framework/OAuthSwift
  Expected in: /Users/nrith/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<blah-blah-blah>.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
```

It looks like something to file a radar against, but before doing that, I just wanted to see whether anyone else has come across this.

The `OAuthSwift` library call that's failing [on line 151 of `OAuthSwiftCredential`](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/blob/master/Sources/OAuthSwiftCredential.swift):

```
open func authorizationHeader(method: OAuthSwiftHTTPRequest.Method, url: URL, parameters: OAuthSwift.Parameters, body: Data? = nil) -> String {
    let timestamp = String(Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970))
    let nonce = OAuthSwiftCredential.generateNonce()
    return self.authorizationHeader(method: method, url: url, parameters: parameters, body: body, timestamp: timestamp, nonce: nonce)
}

open class func generateNonce() -> String {
    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    return uuidString.substring(to: 8)
}
```

Specifically, the `uuidString.substring(to: 8)` is failing.

Here's the relevant info from the stack (note that the `generateNonce()` method has been inlined):

[image]

Comment: Did you build the framework yourself?

Comment: I built it with Carthage, and dragged the built framework in. I'm now trying it with a `copy-frameworks` build step.

Comment: That didn't work, either. Hmpf.

Comment: Make sure that your Xcode beta installation is the one selected with `xcode-select` for your build. Swift frameworks won't be portable between different versions of Swift until the ABI is declared stable.

Comment: Good suggestion. What that prints, though, seems legit: `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: Any resolution to this issue.  I'm seeing something similar.

Comment: Nothing I've found. I'm waiting for beta 5 to come out. I still need to confirm that it works as expected on 8.3.2, though, before I file a radar.